# How can I get SSH on Windows like on Linux or OS X

Tags: windows, software-rec, ssh

I'm doing a lot of Ruby/Python development, and it's really hard to get all tools working on Windows, one of the hardest part is making `ssh` command working properly on Windows.

Does anyone who know any tool can do this? I would like to use `ssh` in the Windows `cmd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Putty. I also find useful [WinSCP](http://winscp.net). Not command line but allows you to do a lot of stuff apart from just copying files. Its embeded text editor is quite functional and does not introduce any weird character, etc. In windows, if you are doing a lot of Ruby development, by all means I would recommend you using [RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack).

Answer (score 4):

You can either use [cygwin](http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html) if you want it in a shell-like environment, or use the de facto [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Plink (on the PuTTY page) allows you to use PuTTY's SSH functionality from the Windows command line.