# Windows equivalent of SSH

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, command-line, scp

I don't know Windows very well and only vaguely know my way around the Command Prompt.

Is there an equivalent to SSHing into another Windows computer via cmd? Equivalents to SCP and other Linux commands would be nice as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to have SSH on windows like LINUX OR MAC](http://superuser.com/questions/249672/want-to-have-ssh-on-windows-like-linux-or-mac)

Comment: If you are vaguely aware of cmd, just use Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 16):

PowerShell comes with [Remoting](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_remote.htm) capabilities in WinRM:

```
PS C:\> enter-pssession otherhost
```

In XP, you could use [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553), but this is only recommended over secure LANs:

```
psexec \\otherhost cmd
```

Comment: I found [HTG's Powershell remoting guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) easier and quicker to follow.

Answer (score 12):

**[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)** for shell access.

[image]

**[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/)** (UI, no cmd) for file transfers.

[image]

Comment: well, winscp and putty are only the client-parts of the problem OP has. you also need the ssh-server on the other windows machines ... the 2nd part of "Is there an equivalent to SSHing into another Windows computer via cmd" ...

Comment: PuTTY includes `PSFTP`, which is a command-line sftp client.

Comment: WinSCP *does* have a command-line version, part of the main package.

Comment: @grawity: Yeah, but it's actually a `.com` command line interface to the full `.exe` application, which is needed for it to work.  You of course know that, but I thought I'd just mention that.

Answer (score 6):

In order to connect another Windows computer using SSH, an SSH server would have to be running on the that computer.  SSH isn't part of Windows, so this would have to be installed and configured.  Take a look at [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) if this is what you're interested in doing.  (Cygwin will also provide you a more familiar feeling command-line SSH, as well as other familiar Unix tools.)

If you're looking for the "Windows way" of doing these things, have a look at Remote Desktop (although it is graphical, not command-line based).

You can enable Remote Access on the target machine which will allow you to connect to it with Remote Desktop.  You can also transfer files back and forth by mapping a drive back to your own computer if you configure your connection to allow access to local resources.

Answer (score 2):

I've always felt uncomfortable advising the use of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) for one single function. There is an alternative, however: [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=overview). The project, unfortunately, is quite inactive, but it should be a match to Cygwin, especially if you don't want to clutter your PATH and other variables.

When installed and configured, you can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) for ssh access.

Answer (score 1):

+1 The PuTTY developer also provides pscp (for scp) psftp (for sftp) and several other programs for agents etc.. (See the [Downloads](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) section for details on the programs) For more traditional *nix commands, you can download [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (which also has scp etc..) or, if you're trying to transition into the windows world depending on your windows version, [powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can make the transition, from a scripting and command aliasing position, a little less painful.